# Returning a vector for a given threshold in r

Tags: r

I have written the code below - for a given threshold, it is supposed to add up the numbers until it gets below or equal to that threshold for e.g. (0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4) - 0+1+1+1 = 3 and the provide the number of iterations, i.e. 4.  It seems to work, but not for a vector for e.g. [1:10] - what am I doing wrong?

```
sumf<-function(y){
    sum<-0
    for(i in 1:(length(y))){
        sum=sum+y[i]
    }
    print(sum) 
}

sumf(x<n)
```

Comment: Pleease show the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `cumsum`.

```
x <- c(0, 6, 3, 8, 5, 2, 4, 0, 2, 2)
data.frame(id = 1:length(x), x, sum = cumsum(x))

   id x sum
1   1 0   0
2   2 6   6
3   3 3   9
4   4 8  17
5   5 5  22
6   6 2  24
7   7 4  28
8   8 0  28
9   9 2  30
10 10 2  32
```